# Add Method - Object in another NS

Tags: c#, .net, forms-authentication, .net-4.6

Maybe I am looking at this wrong but I have been doing so for little over an hour.

1. I first tried an Extension method, but that was not productive.
2. Trying to extend the `FormsAuthentication` class to include a `static` method to return a concatenated value that is the same pattern sprinkled all over various root points.

Current Code (Option #2):

```
public partial class FormsAuthentication {
    public static string FormsUserCookieName () {
        return FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + '_' + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

The only thing I have not done, is created a Namespace file for the `FormsAuthentication` "extension" to be located.

Quite frankly, unsure if "psyching" the compiler into the resident namespace will perform any differently.

Any Suggestions on the best approach will be greatly appreciated.

## Update

Based on discussions and review, seems the best approach was to implement a property for the Page class inherited by each page.

```
public class WebsitePage : Page {
    ....
    public string FormsUserCookieName { get { return FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + '_' + User.Identity.Name; } }
    ....
}
```

Comment: Did you read [how to create an extension-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)? Your syntax doesn´t fit.

Comment: @HimBromBeere `extensions` are easy but they only apply to instance-based extensions not static, from what I know of them.  I need to be able to add a static method to the class.

Comment: That won´t work and is not possible. You can´t *modify* an existing class, not even extension-methods do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to create an [extension-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Actually those do not really extend the class `FormsAuthentication`, as they reside in their own class and are completely independend of the extended class. Have a look at this example:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string FormsUserCookieName (this FormsAuthentication) {
        return FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + '_' + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

This can now be used as if it *were* defined within `FormsAuthentication`, if you´d included the namespace where `MyExtensions` is defined. Thus you can write this now:

```
myInstanceOfFormsAuthentication.FormsUserCookieName();
```

However the method doesn´t really belong to that class, it is defined within `MyExtensions`-class and thus equivalent to the following:

```
MyExtensions.FormsUserCookieName(myInstanceOfFormsAuthentication);
```

Another approach is simply to have a wrapping-class around `FormsAuthentication`:

```
class FormsAuthenticationEx
{
    public static string FormsUserCookieName() { ... }
}
```

This is much clearer to the user of your API as it shows where your extensions are defined.

Comment: Problem is that I will never have an instance of the FormsAuthentication class, i guess.  I was looking to do this as a static method, since all of the references are static based.

Comment: Closest answer but even the Wrapper design won't work.  Decided on centralizing the pattern into a Page base-class.  isolates the repeated pattern for each page into a single property `public string FormsUserCookieName { get { return FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName + '_' + User.Identity.Name; } }
`

Answer (score 1):

Extending the class won't work. All parts of a class must be marked partial and must be defined in the same assembly. You will never achieve the latter and as the class is defined as:

`public sealed class FormsAuthentication`

It is not partial and like most .NET Framework classes it is sealed.

Your only option is to create an extension method.

Comment: That was my fear....but how would I extend the `FormsAuthentication` class to allow for a static method?  If its not possible, i am kewl with that.  Just looking for possible pattern that I have not been exposed to.

Comment: Use the standard mechanism in .NET to create extension methods.